# How to map an array of arrays and just return it

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays, and I want to map over it and just return the values of arrays, but when I map over it and log the result, it's just an array and I don't know how to map over my array and use it in other places.

```
 const arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
  ];

  const arrMap = arr.map((it) => it.map((itm) => itm));
  console.log(arrMap);


//what I expected 1,2,3,4,5,6 , ...
//what I got [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
```

Actually, I need the values for using them in somewhere else, but I don't know what to do.
I also used function for this but when I return the values and log them It's undefined:

```
  const arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
  ];

  
  const arrMap = (arr) => {
    arr.forEach((element) => {
      console.log(element);
//In here, everything works fine
      return element;
    });
  };
  console.log(arrMap);

//what I got undefined
```

Comment: You get undefined because `console.log` doesn't return anything.  Your `arrMap` is a function, try calling it: `console.log(arrMap(arr));`

Comment: @MikeM what would expect that to return?

Comment: @Andy Undefined, but it will at least log the elements. Clearly, the function needs to be called.

Answer (score 5):

Use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) -

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
];

const arrMap = arr.flatMap(m => m);
console.log(arrMap);
```

Comment: Might want to add [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Why it won't work :** `map()` is supposed to run on each element of an array and return a **transformed array of the same length**. You have three elements in your input array and will always get three elements in your mapped array.

Your expectations can be met by tweaking your code with `forEach()` if you want. With `forEach()` there is nothing returned and you will have to start with a separate array variable. Below code uses [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
  ];

  let arrMap = [];
  arr.forEach((it) => arrMap.push(...it));
  console.log(arrMap);
```

But [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is already there:

```js
 const arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
  ];
  
  let ans = arr.flatMap(x => x);
  console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

forEach doesn't return anything it's like a for loop but for array only.
Since you have double array you should flat it by using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```
  const arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
  ];
  const arrMap = arr.flatMap((it) => it);
  console.log(arrMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) if you just want to flatten the array:

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
];

console.log(arr.flat());
```

Use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) if you want to do something with each element before the array gets flattened.

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
];

const arrMap = arr.flatMap((el) => {
  el.forEach((n) => console.log(n));
  return el;
});

console.log(arrMap);
```